# Raspberry Pi, Multi LED light colour sequence

Tags: python-3.x, colors, raspberry-pi3, led

I am writing a specific program.

This program is supposed to work with a Raspberry Pi,

I will be using Raspbian with Python.

I want to try and make a colour sequence using really simple print statements.

I want to be able to adapt this code for the raspberry pi.

Here's my code so far, but I wanted to put seperate colours, the reason for this is because there ware going to be seperate LEDs on the breadboard, each that have a different colour.

I also want the program to end, once I press a key, but i don't really know if I'm doing any of this right.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import RPi.GPIO
import time
LED = ["Red", "Pink", "Green", "Purple"]
def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setwarnings(false)
print ("LED On!")

def led():
    while True:
        GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(1)

def destroy():
    GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.cleanup()

setup()
try:
    led()
except KeyboardInterrupt:


destroy()
```

Comment: Have you tried your code on a Raspberry ? This should blink the LED wired on the pin 18 on and off.

Comment: The code works, but there are certain things I want it to do. E.g. Terminate the program when a certain combination of buttons are pressed like "CTRL + C". I've since then expanded the code if you want to have a look?

Comment: Alright, maybe your question should be more precise on what exactly you want to do and that your code doesn't do. If you want to stop your code after `CTRL+C`, you can just add `return` in the line below `except KeyboardInterrupt:`